# Groovy and Maven: Stuck in compiling and testing a very simple

Tags: maven, unit-testing, groovy, compilation, resources

I am stuck trying to compile and test a extremely simple project. It's a beginner project in order to understand how all of this works, and I am currently stucked.

My main objective is to understand how to handle resources files that are located outside of the standard folder structure.

I have a main class, with two methods. One load a resource file which is on the standard folder structure (`src\main\resources`). Another one load a resource which is in a custom folder, outside of the standard structure (`resources`).

There is one junit file that simply verify that the resource is correctly loaded.

It works fine with IntelliJ. I simply declared the resources folder as resources folders and that's it.

Now with maven ..... actually I can't even compile with gmaven-plus. Nor run the test. So I did not even bother to declare the custom folder as a resource in the pom.xml file.

I based my pom.xml file based on an existing pom we have at work and from stuff I read on the web. There's no way I can make it work.

Here is a link to a 7zip file with my project, if one could put me on the right track, I would be grateful.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvn32ll5xfvjfwd/GroovyExample.7z?dl=0

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    <directory>src/main/groovy</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                            <testSources>
                                <testSource>
                                    <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </testSource>
                            </testSources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
                    <testSourceDirectory>str/test/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the output:

> Unable to get Groovy version from InvokerHelper or GroovySystem,
>   trying jar name.
>
> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.8.1:compile (default) on
>   project Example: Execution default of goal
>   org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.8.1:compile failed.

Comment: Please add the POM and the build output to your question. The question should be understandable without external resources like a dropbox link.

Comment: Done, there's now the pom and the output in the original post

Comment: I had no difficulty doing this with Java, it's only groovy the issue.

Comment: the dependency section is missing in `org.codehaus.gmavenplus` plugin section

https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Usage

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. So basically gmavenplus is like a nested pom in the maven pom file.

Answer (score 1):

The 2.4 groovy-all POMs do not include Groovy as a dependency, because they are a POM for an uber-jar, rather than a POM that describes all the Groovy module jars.  Because of this, GMavenPlus is unable to find the Groovy jar to use for compilation.  The `<type>pom</type>` works for Groovy 2.5, and 3.0, but not 2.4.  So for your use case, simply delete the `<type>pom</type>` (or replace it with the default of `<type>jar</type>`).  This was the way Groovy was often included back before 2.5, so the groovy-all POMs of 2.5 and 3.0 were added to ease the transition.  See https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html#Groovy2.5releasenotes-Packaging.